# SQL Spatial Table and trailing white space issues

Tags: sql-server, mapinfo, table, spectrum-spatial-analyst

When accessing a table from our MSSQL Server via MapInfo, none of the fields contain trailing white spaces, the same holds true when exported to CSV via MapInfo.

However, when exporting the same table from Management Studio, all the fields have quite a few consistent amount of trailing white spaces, this is causing issues when using the tables in Spectrum.

I have tried doing a field update with the RTrim function in MapInfo but nothing changes.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

PS: Only certain tables exhibit this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue at some point with EasyLoader where it added trailing spaces to character columns when uploading the table to SQL Server.

One solution is to trim the column in SQL Server with a statement like this:

```
Update dbo.[SOME_TABLE_NAME] 
   Set [SOME_COLUMN_NAME] = RTRIM([SOME_COLUMN_NAME])
```

where dbo is the schema, SOME_TABLE_NAME is the name of the table and SOME_COLUMN_NAME is the name of the column.